# concatenate vectors from a lists of lists

Tags: r

I would like to have a general solution to a certain problem. 
I have a nested list; each element of this list is a list with named elements. For example:

```
mylist <- list(
  list(x1 = 1:10, x2 = letters[1:5]),
  list(x1 = 11:14, x2 = letters[6:15])
)
```

here `mylist[[1]]` and `mylist[[2]]` each have vectors `x1` and `x2`.

I would like to concatenate all the `x1` vectors and `x2` vectors, such as to obtain:

```
c(mylist[[1]]$x1, mylist[[2]]$x1)
c(mylist[[1]]$x2, mylist[[2]]$x2)
```

but for a general case where `mylist` might have `n` elements.

If I knew a priori that `mylist` has only two elements, then I could use

```
do.call(function(a,b) c(a$x1, b$x1), mylist)
do.call(function(a,b) c(a$x2, b$x2), mylist)
```

but I do not know how to generalize this for `n` elements.

Comment: See `?.mapply` -- `.mapply(c, mylist, NULL)` or, the more convenient interface `do.call(Map, c(c, mylist))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
vecs <- unlist(mylist, recursive = F)
lapply(unique(names(vecs)), function(name) do.call(c, vecs[name == names(vecs)]))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this using the [tidyverse](http://tidyverse.org) then:

```
library(tidyverse)
```

Edit based on comment from @jbaums and noting that `flatten` returns a list not a vector:

```
purrr::transpose(mylist) %>% purrr::map(unlist)
```

Comment: This would require an additional `%>% lapply(unlist)` (or maybe a tidyverse alternative). But then you could also just do `purrr::transpose(mylist) %>% lapply(unlist)`.

Comment: Good point on the unlist. `purrr::flatten` leaves the output as a list. The type variants `flatten_chr` and `flatten_dbl` won't work without adding more complexity to check type for x1 and x2 (and it's not clear in question on stability of type of x1 and x2).